# ValueError: Cannot assign to variable conv1_conv/kernel:0 due to variable shape (7, 7, 1, 64) and value shape (64, 3, 7, 7) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network

I am facing an issue using Resnet, Since i am new to this model it is a bit hard to find what might have gone wrong. Initially i tried to use the input shape as (10, 224, 224, 1) but this works only for 2d cnn or 3d cnn models but not for Resnet. Is there a workaround or i have to use only CNN models?

Please give your input.

resizing part of code is here

```
def 10frames(dataset,directory):
    frames=[]
    for i in np.arange(len(dataset)):
        vid_name=dataset.video_name[i].split(".")[0]
        vid_dir_path=os.path.join(directory,vid_name)
        frames_to_select=[]
        for l in np.arange(0,10):
            frames_to_select.append('frame%d.jpg' % l)
        vid_data=[]
        for frame in frames_to_select:
            image=Image.open(os.path.join(vid_dir_path,frame))
            image=image.resize((224, 224,1), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
            datu=np.asarray(image)
            normu_dat=datu/255
            vid_data.append(normu_dat)
        vid_data=np.array(vid_data)
        frames.append(vid_data)
    return np.array(frames)
```

Rest of code

```
print(train_dataset_new.shape)
print(test_dataset_new.shape)
print(test_labels.shape)
print(train_labels.shape)

(64, 10, 224, 224)
(23, 10, 224, 224)
(23,)
(64,)

test_dataset_new=test_dataset_new.reshape((23,10,224,224,1))
train_dataset_new=train_dataset_new.reshape((64,10,224,224,1))


trainAug = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")
valAug = ImageDataGenerator()
mean = np.array([123.68, 116.779, 103.939], dtype="float32")
trainAug.mean = mean
valAug.mean = mean

baseModel = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224,1)))


# construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the
# the base model
headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(512, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(214, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)
# place the head FC model on top of the base model (this will become
# the actual model we will train)
model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)
# loop over all layers in the base model and freeze them so they will
# *not* be updated during the training process
for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

The error points me in the input shape

```
Error

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-6bf65adc9696> in <module>()
----> 1 baseModel = ResNet50(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,     input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224,1)))
      2 
      3 
      4 # construct the head of the model that will be placed on top of the
      5 # the base model

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/resource_variable_ops.py in assign(self, value, use_locking, name, read_value)
    889             ("Cannot assign to variable%s due to variable shape %s and value "
    890              "shape %s are incompatible") %
--> 891             (tensor_name, self._shape, value_tensor.shape))
    892       assign_op = gen_resource_variable_ops.assign_variable_op(
    893           self.handle, value_tensor, name=name)

ValueError: Cannot assign to variable conv1_conv/kernel:0 due to variable shape (7, 7, 1, 64) and value shape (64, 3, 7, 7) are incompatible
```

Comment: Imagenet weights assume you have a 3-channel input, not a one channel input as you have in your input shape, that is probably the problem.

Comment: if i change it to 3 channel then it would mean that the image net is going to work only with RGB images and there wont be point in changing it to black and white in my first part of code

Comment: Let me repeat, Imagenet weights are only available for RGB images, not grayscale images.,

Comment: ok I get it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was using python3.8 with tensorflow. When I changed back to python3.6 with tensorflow, it works well with no errors.